# Optmising a MySQL left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know if this is just wishful thinking, my wrong thinking or something else:

```
select 
f1,
f2,
f3
from f_import as a
left join e_im_com_codes on a.customer = e_im_com_codes.customer 
and a.cc8 = e_im_com_codes.Code
where e_im_com_codes.Code is null
and a.customer = 'd'
and a.hide = false;
```

This results in a plan that looks like:

```
    +----+-------------+----------------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table          | partitions | type | possible_keys                              | key            | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f_import       | NULL       | ref  | idx_cc8_import,idx_com_code                | idx_cc8_import | 768     | const | 216782 |    10.00 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e_im_com_codes | NULL       | ALL  | e_im_com_codes_idx,e_im_com_codes_customer | NULL           | NULL    | NULL  |   1698 |    10.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+------+--------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

But takes around a minute to run.

Anyone got any suggestions as to a query based optimisation? Or do I need to rework the database a little?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `not exists` instead:

```
select i.f1, i.f2, i.f3
from f_import i
where i.customer = 'd' and
      i.hide = false and
      not exists (select 1
                  from e_im_com_codes icc
                  where i.customer = icc.customer and
                        i.cc8 = icc.Code
                 );
```

Then for this, you want an index on `f_import(customer, hide)` and `e_im_com_codes(customer, code)`

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that shaved 15 seconds off it, still slower than I'd like though, might have to rework the table to store the unmatching records more effectively.

Comment: @TomBarber . . . You can try adding `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` to the `f_import` index as the last three columns.

Answer (score 0):

First you should add indexes on the following columns:

```
f_import.customer 
f_import.cc8
f_import.customer
f_import.hide

e_im_com_codes.customer
e_im_com_codes.Code
```

Then I see no reason why the query should be slow.

Comment: Thanks André. I've got indexes on those columns, as you can see from the plan, its not using a temp file or anything to deal with the slowness, so I don't believe its a direct indexing issue. Not done MySQL optimisation in a while though, so I might be wrong :)